# Error al hacer debug de un proyecto en VScode en C++

Tags: c++, vscode

Soy novato utilizando VScode y al compilar mi proyecto, el .exe generado no recibo salida alguna. Por tanto intento hacer debug del proyecto para encontrar el fallo, el terminal me devuelve los siguientes fallos:

> *main.cpp:24: undefined reference to tomar_datosabi:cxx11'*
>
> *main.cpp:24: undefined reference to
> ejercicio_1(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,   std::char_traits,
> std::allocator >)'*
>
> *main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `imprimir(bool)'*

Adicionalmente, aparece una ventana emergente que afirma que main.exe no existe y preguntando si deseo abrir *launcher.json*

¿A que se deben estos fallos?

Este es el código de los módulos:
Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "E_S_caracteres.hpp"
#include <string>
#include "operaciones_pila.hpp"

void menu();

int main()
{
   menu();
   return 0;
}

void menu ()
{
int selec;
std::cout << "Este es el menu de la practica 4; Que ejercicio deseas comprobar" << std::endl;
std::cin >> selec;

switch(selec)
{
    case(1):imprimir(ejercicio_1(tomar_datos()));
    break;
    default: std::cout << "ERROR, esa opcion no esta implementada o no existe" << std::endl;
}
}
```

E_S_caracteres.cpp

```
#include "E_S_caracteres.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

//Precondicion:
//Postcondicion: Devuelve una cadena de n caracteres tomados de la entrada estandar.
std::string tomar_datos()
{
std::string cadena;
std::cout << "Introduce la cadena, cumpliendo con los requisitos del problema :" << std::endl;
std::cin>> cadena;

return cadena; 
}

//Precondicion: La funcion es llamada por otra que proporciona un booleano no vacio.
//Postcondcion: Devuelve por la salida estandar el resultado del valor proporcionado
void imprimir(bool sn)
{
if (sn == true) std::cout << " Es cierto";
else std::cout << "Falso, no se ha cumplido";
}
```

Operaciones_pila.cpp:

```
#include "pilavec1.hpp"
#include <string>


//Precondicion: Recibe una cadena de caracteres (vacía o no).
//Postcondicion: devuelve si la secuencia de caracteres de forma X&Y esta formando en
//cadenas inversas divididas por &.
bool ejercicio_1(std::string cadena)// Pregunta: ¿Es la forma mas eficiente?
{

int tam,i = 0;
tam = cadena.length();//obtener longitud de cadena
Pila<char> P1(tam);

while( i < tam)
{
if (cadena.at(i) == '&') //comparacion
{
    i++; //Pasamos & para empezar la comparacion de cadenas
    while (i < tam)
    {
        if(P1.tope() != cadena.at(i)) return false;
        P1.pop();
        i++;
    }
}
else //copia del valor a pila
{
    P1.push(cadena.at(i));
    i++;
}
} 
return true;
}
```

Los respectivos .hpp contienen la cabecera de las funciones solamente.

Comment: Puedes compartir el comando con el que se esta compilando? Lo mas probable es que se esten omitiendo algunos archivos.

Comment: Mediante g++. El comando es g++ main.cpp operaciones_pila.cpp  operaciones_pila.hpp E_S_caracteres.cpp E_S_caracteres.hpp pilavec1.hpp -o main.exe